# C error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Full error message

> dll.c:89:13: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'
>                   arr2[i] = &(*remove)(list);

My function is supposed to take 4 parameters, an two arrays, a length value, a remove function, and an insert function. It then takes the values of the first array and puts them in a linked list. Then it removes the values from the linked list and inserts them into the 2nd array. The part that Im having trouble with is inserting the values into the second array. I know the problem has to do with my understanding of pointers. I know the arrays are `void *` and my remove function returns `void *` so initially I tried `arr2[i] = (*remove)(list)` but I also got a compiler error. So I added the `&` just because this has seemed to work in the past ( I know not a good reason ) and now I get this error. Thanks for any help.

```
   void transfer(char *arr1, char *arr2, int length, void (*insert)(List *, void *), void* (*remove)(List *)) {
    List *list = List_create();

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        (*insert)(list, &arr1[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = &(*remove)(list);
    }
}
```

Header File

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;

List *List_create(void);

void add_to_back(List *list, void *value);
void *remove_from_back(List *list);

void add_to_front(List *list, void *value);
void *remove_from_front(List *list);

void transfer(void *arr1, void *arr2, int length, void (*insert)(List *, void *), void* (*remove)(List *));
```

Comment: The message does not look like from a C compiler. If you use a C++ compiler, change the tags or try a C compiler. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: `void *` is a placeholder type that's used when the pointer can point to any type of object. Since the types of the array elements aren't known, you can't index it. A function like this needs to take a `size` parameter that comes from `sizeof (elementType)` in the caller.

Comment: Your function pointer `remove` returns `void`, not `void *`.  If you call this function passing as parameter an address of a function that actually returns `void *`, you should see the compiler complaining.  It would help if you showed how you call this function (and also the function whose address you pass in)

Comment: I haven't yet called the `transfer` function

Comment: “_Just because this has seemed to work in the past (I know not a good reason)_” is **not** a good approach! Do try to understand what goes wrong and why corrections work!

Comment: @PJTraill Easier said than done when it comes to C. But I think I get it now. You use the `&` to take a value on the stack and get its address so you can save that adress to a pointer. Now that pointer points to that value.

Comment: You can use `&` to get the address of anything that _has_ a definite address: it could just as well be a `static` variable or something allocated on the heap (in which case what `malloc` returns _is_ the address). You can take the address of a variable holding a pointer, but not of an expression returning a pointer. It does all take a while to get your head round, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody, would you mind looking at my 2nd attempt at the problem which has resulted in segmentation fault? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488554/c-program-to-transfer-contents-of-one-array-to-another-results-in-segmentation-f

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your `remove` function is

```
void remove(List *);
```

you call it here:

```
arr2[i] = &(*remove)(list);
```

but as the return value is `void` it's like

```
// arr2[i] = &(void);
```

I think you meant that remove returns a pointer to the removed element, but then the signature should be like:

```
void* remove(List *);
```

as a function pointer:

```
void* (*remove)(List *))
```

Comment: I updated my signature to the following void `transfer(void *arr1, void *arr2, int length, void (*insert)(List *, void *), void* (*remove)(List *))` but Im still getting the same error

Comment: How do you call your `transfer` method? How does the signature of the declaration/definition of `remove` look like? It is not enough if you only adjust the signature of your function parameter.

Comment: Actuallly the error message is a little different `error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void *'`. I haven't called transfer yet but I'll post my header file with the add and remove functions

Comment: If I remove `&` I get the following error `error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable arr2[i] = (*remove)(list);`

Comment: @Daniel Kobe As @Barmar said in the comment above, you also cannot access your `arr1` and `arr2` elements by index i, because it is a void pointer and not an array. This should emit an error/warning as well.