# C program to transfer contents of one array to another results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

C beginner here. My `transfer` function is supposed to take 5 parameters, two arrays (first array has values the other is empty), a length value for the arrays, a size of value, a remove function, and an insert function. It then takes the values of the first array and puts them in a linked list. Then it removes the values from the linked list and inserts them into the 2nd array. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error message when the `transfer` function runs in `test.c` file.

> Segmentation fault: 11

#### Here are my files, dll.c

```
#include <dll.h>

List *List_create(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}

void add_to_back(List *list, void *value)
{  
    ListNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    node->value = value;

    if (list->first == NULL) {
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    } else {
        list->last->next = node;
        node->prev = list->last;
        list->last = node;
    }

    list->count++;
}

void *remove_from_back(List *list)
{
    void *result = NULL;

    if (list->last == NULL) return result;

    ListNode *dead_node = list->last;
    result = list->last->value;

    if (list->last->value == list->first->value) {
        list->last = list->first = NULL;    
    } else {
        list->last = list->last->prev;
        list->last->next = NULL;        
    }   
    free(dead_node);
    return result;
}

void add_to_front(List *list, void *value)
{
    ListNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    node->value = value;

    if (list->first == NULL) {
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    } else {
        list->first->prev = node;
        node->next = list->first;
        list->first = node;
    }

    list->count++;
}

void *remove_from_front(List *list)
{
    void *result = NULL;

    if (list->first == NULL) return result;

    ListNode *dead_node = list->first;
    result = list->first->value;

    if (list->last->value == list->first->value) {
        list->last = list->first = NULL;    
    } else {
        list->first = list->first->next;
        list->first->prev = NULL;       
    }   
    free(dead_node);
    return result;
    return 0;
}

void transfer(void **arr1, void **arr2, int length, int size, void (*insert)(List *, void *), void* (*remove)(List *)) {
    List *list = List_create();

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        (*insert)(list, &arr1[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        void *indexPtr = arr2 + i*size;
        indexPtr = (*remove)(list);
    }
}
```

#### test.c

```
#include <dll.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test_add_to_back(void) {
    List *list = List_create();

    int new_value = 1;
    add_to_back(list, &new_value);
    ListNode *curr = list->first;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;
    if (list->first->value != list->last->value || list->last->value != &new_value) return 0;

    new_value = 2;
    add_to_back(list, &new_value);  
    new_value = 3;
    add_to_back(list, &new_value);  
    new_value = 4;
    add_to_back(list, &new_value);  
    curr = list->first;

    new_value = 4;
    if (list->last->value != &new_value) return 0;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;
    curr = curr->next;
    new_value = 2;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;
    curr = curr->next;
    new_value = 3;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;
    curr = curr->next;
    new_value = 4;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int test_remove_from_back(void) {
    List *list = List_create();
    char *test1 = "test1 data";
    char *test2 = "test2 data";
    char *test3 = "test3 data";

    add_to_back(list, test1);
    add_to_back(list, test2);
    add_to_back(list, test3);

    if (remove_from_back(list) != test3) return 0;
    if (remove_from_back(list) != test2) return 0;
    if (remove_from_back(list) != test1) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int test_add_to_front(void) {
    List *list = List_create();
    char *test1 = "test1 data";
    char *test2 = "test2 data";
    char *test3 = "test3 data";

    add_to_front(list, test1);
    add_to_front(list, test2);
    add_to_front(list, test3);

    ListNode *head = list->first;
    if (head->value != test3) return 0;
    head = head->next;
    if (head->value != test2) return 0;
    head = head->next;
    if (head->value != test1) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int test_remove_from_front(void) {
    List *list = List_create();
    char *test1 = "test1 data";
    char *test2 = "test2 data";
    char *test3 = "test3 data";

    add_to_back(list, test1);
    add_to_back(list, test2);
    add_to_back(list, test3);

    if (remove_from_front(list) != test1) return 0;
    if (remove_from_front(list) != test2) return 0;
    if (remove_from_front(list) != test3) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int test_transfer(void) {
    #define ARRAY_LENGTH 10
    void *arr1[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        arr1[i] = &i;
    }

    void *ptr;
    void *arr2[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        arr2[i] = ptr;
    }

    transfer(arr1, arr2, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof(int), (*add_to_front), (*remove_from_front));

    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *((int *)arr2[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("helloworld\n");
    if(test_add_to_back() != 1) printf("Add to back test failed\n");
    else printf("Add to back test passed\n");

    if(test_remove_from_back() != 1) printf("Remove from back test failed\n");
    else printf("Remove from back test passed\n");

    if(test_add_to_front() != 1) printf("Add to back test failed\n");
    else printf("Add to back test passed\n");

    if(test_remove_from_front() != 1) printf("Remove from front test failed\n");
    else printf("Remove from front test passed\n");

    test_transfer();

    return 0;
}
```

I also have a `dll.h` file but I didn't include it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What have you done to debug this program? What tools did you use? What results did you get? Where did you get stuck? Is your question "how do you debug a segmentation fault?" If so, take out all that irrelevant code and tell us about your platform and tools.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve] (TL;DR).

Comment: In `test_transfer()`, `arr2[i] = ptr;` uses the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate, which is undefined behavior.